# iPad iOS4 dictionary count returns 0

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios4, nsdictionary

I am checking that the entries in my dictionary are not 0 using NSDictionary count. It works and returns the correct number except on iPad 4.3 Simulator and iPads running iOS 4.3.
Is this a known bug in iOS 4 or am I seeing a side effect of something else I am doing which is iOS 4 incompatible?

edit:

Thank you for your comments so far! I am happy to believe that it's my code; I'm new to this.  Here is a greatly simplified version of my code.

```
-(NSDictionary *)dictionaryOfSets
{
    if (!_dictionaryOfSets)
    {
        NSOrderedSet* set1 = [[NSOrderedSet alloc] initWithObjects:
            [NSNumber numberWithInt:(1)],
            [NSNumber numberWithInt:(2)],
            [NSNumber numberWithInt:(3)],
            [NSNumber numberWithInt:(4)],
            nil];
        NSOrderedSet* set2 = [[NSOrderedSet alloc] initWithObjects:
            [NSNumber numberWithInt:(9)],
            [NSNumber numberWithInt:(10)],
            [NSNumber numberWithInt:(11)],
            nil];

        _dictionaryOfSets = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
            set1,  [NSNumber numberWithInt:(1)],
            set2,  [NSNumber numberWithInt:(2)],
            nil];

        [set1 release];
        [set2 release];
    }
    return _dictionaryOfSets;
}
```

Comment: Post some code. `NSDictionary` behavior hasn't changed much since iPhone OS 1.0.

Comment: Yes, it's a known bug ... in your code.

Comment: The last time I had this sort of problem I was forgetting to allocate the Dictionary with `dict = [NSDictionary dictionary];`.  How we laughed.

Comment: Well, the code you've posted should work just fine. You said it's a simplified version of your code, is there any code path in your original code that can lead to `_dictionaryOfSets` being nil (i.e. not getting set)?

Comment: No it is a getter on the dictionary. By simplified I mean that it is much smaller and the numbers are consts. I have 64 sets of about 10 entries in each. Otherwise the code is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few weeks of searching and tests I have concluded that NSOrderedSet does not work under iOS 4.3. The same code works under iOS 5.0 and 5.1. I have replaced the NSOrderedSet with NSSet and it now works under iOS 4.3. I am surprised that I haven't found documentation covering that.

Comment: The documentation on `NSOrderedSet` states pretty clearly at the very top that the class is "Available in iOS 5.0 and later".

Comment: omz, could you point that documentation out to me please. It will save a lot of time next time! I have only this link: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSOrderedSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html for which I can't see any reference to 5.0. Oh, and I wish you had said that on 21st Feb. Also, it compiled and ran so I presumed it was good.

Comment: You are looking at the wrong docs... these are for Mac. See [that one](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSOrderedSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: @Alladinian Thank you! They look so similar and I always find documentation simply from a Google search. You have made my day.

Comment: I'd recommend that you use Xcode's built-in documentation viewer. Protip: You can option-click a class/method in your code to view quick infos (which includes availability information). option-doubleclick to search in the full docs.

Answer (score 0):

I would double check that the dictionary isn't nil. Messaging nil in that case - [dict count] - would just do that - return 0.

Comment: The dictionary returns the correct information when I read from it. I am checking for empty with: ASSERT(dictionary.count != 0);

Comment: I tried assert([dictionary count] != 0); too. Same outcome. And added an assert(dictionary != nil); but that is not firing.

Comment: if assert(dict != nil) is true (no error message) its something else - yup. You could set break points (debugger) and try to 'see' what happens to the dict contents.